# Alternative to load() in jQuery 3 For Loading Bootstrap 4 Modal Remote Content

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, jquery-3

Loading another page/content (aka "remote" content) into a Bootstrap Modal has been the bane of many developer, and great solutions like this one work:

```
$('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
  $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Using the above allows you to make one script call, and have it apply for any pages that have modals that load content, be it local or remote. It should be noted that for "local" modals, you cannot have an `href` attribute (even one with a hash for the value) for this to work for both (local and remote). This could be included in a footer file or any other globally-included file in your application so it only resides in one place, and works for every modal in your application.

However, with jQuery 3, the `load()` method has been depreciated, so how would one go about loading remote modal content in light of this?

I know you can use `ajax()`, but is there a way to construct it to be more 'dynamic' like my example above so there isn't a need to have a unique script for every modal?

Comment: So thanks to @Taplar, here is the solution so one script can be used to load modals locally or with remote content:
```$('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"][href]', function(){
  $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
 });```

This ideally should be in a script that is included globally in your application, like a footer file so any page that potentially has a modal (local or remote), it will fire correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load was removed as the shortcut event handler binding, not for loading external resources.

--binding, removed
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

--method to load ajax data, still valid
http://api.jquery.com/load/

As such, since your logic is using the second version, it is still valid in 3x.

Comment: If my logic is valid, then why when using jQuery Migrate, I get these warnings in the console:

`JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated`

I'm using jQuery Migrate 3.0.0

Comment: It may be possible that the migration tool is unable to distinguish between the two different forms of load, and simply gives that if it sees the method on the namespace.  Or maybe you are using the deprecated first form some where else in the code base.

Comment: As I mentioned, the goal in having the logic abstracted like this is so there is one script to manage any modal, local or remote. I have this code in a globally-included footer file, so any pages that have a modal in my application can use this script to handle modal loads. I'll try commenting out jQuery Migrate and see if the modals still work (since the purpose of Migrate is to add in the APIs that they deprecated in jQuery 3).

Comment: UPDATE: Sure enough, the modals still work (so you are likely correct), but now with local modals (e.g., modals whose content is on the existing calling page and not loaded remotely) and even though they work, they throw the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` which I am guessing due to there not being an `href` in my calling link for the local modal.

Comment: You could put a conditional around your load statement that checks if the element has an href on it.  Or actually add that to your child selector.  Add '[href]' to it.  `'[data-toggle="modal"][href]'`

Comment: That solved it! Adding the `[href]` works for both elements that do not have an `href` and those who do (and contain the URL to the remote content being loaded into the modal). Thanks for the quick reply and assistance!